# Check if multiple cell ranges are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple tables that use the same ID values but have different items and descriptions assigned to them. The ID order is fixed and same in all tables.

What I'd like to do is find out which table rows are the same across all tables.

```
     A  B  C     D  E  F     G  H  I

1    H1 H2 H3    H1 H2 H3    H1 H2 H3
     -- -- --    -- -- --    -- -- --
2    1  a  a+    1  a  a+    1  c  c+    FALSE
3    2  b  b+    2  b  b+    2  b  b+    TRUE
4    3  c  c+    3  x  x+    3  a  a+    FALSE

H1 = ID, same values and order in all tables
H2 = item; order varies by table
H3 = item description; items & descriptions come in fixed pairs
```

What I've done so far is placed them next to each other, and I'm using the following formula in the last column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(COUNTIF(A2:I2; A2:I2) - 3)) = 0
```

1. `COUNTIF` returns the array of the entire multi-table row containing the number of occurrences of each cell's value within that same row. For the three tables in the example, that will be three dupes of each cell per row, or `[3,3,3, 3,3,3, 3,3,3]`.
2. The `-3` part zeroes out the array, `[0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0]`, for rows with matching table values.
3. `ABS` drops the minuses from any potential negative numbers in the array caused by the previous step. This makes sure that, in the last step, only the sums of duped-row arrays can equal zero, while all the other arrays will result in a value >0.
4. `SUMPRODUCT` sums the array and returns a single value that can then be compared to zero, which the second step has assured means that all the tables' values in the current row match. (Actually, a simple `SUM` is a more straightforward choice, but for some reason, unlike `SUMPRODUCT`, it requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula).

Is there a simpler formula or layout I can use to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So, compare the three pairs like this with AND():

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my work I use this solution. Perhaps, it's not perfect but viable. Just compare concatenated values:

```
=A2&B2&C2
=D2&E2&F2
=G2&H2&I2
```

Comment: This could return incorrectly if the expected value is at the beginning of the following column, rather than in the column  it is supposed to be in.

Comment: I always put pipe character in between to avoid this. e.g. `=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(AND(A2=D2,D2=G2,B2=E2,E2=H2,C2=F2,F2=I2),"Full Match","Mismatch")
```

**Results:**

[image]